# Letting users sign up and sign in to Azure Portal using AD B2C local accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806889/logging-in-to-azure-ad-b2c-portal-with-social-identity), I need to implement a user flow that enables users to sign up to my Azure AD and then sign in to the Azure Portal to manage everything.

So far I added a user flow with which one can create an account with email, user name and other attributes. While they can use the credential to login to my web app, I'm not sure how do they login to the portal.

It looks like:

- Azure AD tenant domain: *foo.net*
- Email of the user: *brah@hoge.com*
- User name: *brah*
- Display name: *fuga*
- Password: *piyo*

When going to https://portal.azure.com/ and input *brah@foo.net* in "email", the dialog prompts to input the password. However *piyo* is declined and he cannot login to the portal.

Also, even he signs in to the portal by using *brah@hoge.com* (his own azure account), he cannot switch the directory to *foo.net*.

Besides manually creating a user in Azure AD Blade in the portal, how do I let them to create their account to login to the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Azure portal for managing subscriptions and resources that are linked to an Azure AD tenant, then users must be added as [members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#work-account) or [guests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#guest-user) to this Azure AD tenant.

Users can't be added as [consumers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user) to the Azure AD tenant.

You might want to consider either [inviting the external users as guests to your Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator) or [providing an online service for the external users to be added as guests to your Azure AD tenant](https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web).

Comment: Now I understand the difference. Thanks for your suggestion.